# deleting last array value ? php

Tags: php, arrays

1 question type

```
$transport = array('foot', 'bike', 'car', 'plane');
```

can i delete the plane ?
is there a way ?

2 question type

```
 $transport = array('', 'bike', 'car', ''); // delate the last line
 $transport = array('', 'bike', 'car', 'ferrari'); // dont the last line
 $transport = array('ship', 'bike', 'car', 'ferrari'); // dont the last line
```

is there a easy way to delete the last array " if last array value is empty then delete " if not empty then don't delete ? but not to delete the first array ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
if(empty($transport[count($transport)-1])) {
    unset($transport[count($transport)-1]);
}
```

Comment: this one is great, but see roddik comment, `if ($transport[count($transport)-1] === '')` works well and perfect, thanks .

Comment: Glad you found what you needed. Just so you understand, roddik's code will delete the last element from the array if it is an empty string. Mine will delete the last element if it is false, null or any of the other values that the empty() function considers empty. Probably either will work fine for you.

Comment: @GTorodov: No, I don't. The request is to delete the last element if it is empty.

Comment: this one seems to make trouble when adding elements with `$transport[] = "new_element"` later on. I personaly recommend `array_pop()`

Comment: @frieder: What "trouble"? This doesn't do anything to the array other than remove the last element if it is empty. `array_pop()` is a perfectly good method, but this one does not prevent adding anything to the array.

Comment: it might be a PHP-bug. I had an array, lets say `$array = [[0] => "string1", [1] => "string2"]`. Then I removed the last element with `unset($array[1])`. Now When I add an element using `$array[] = "string1"` the array will look like this: `$array = [[0] => "string1", [2] => "string2"]`

Comment: Be aware of what frieder just pointed out on the last message

Comment: There is already a PHP function for this ( `array_pop()` ) and removing it with custom code is not considered a best practice.

Answer (score 34):

The easiest way: [array_pop()](http://www.php.net/array_pop) which will pop an element of the end of the array.

As for the 2nd question:

```
if (end($transport) == "") { 
    array_pop($transport); 
}
```

Should handle the second.

EDIT:

Modified the code to conform to the updated information. This should work with associative or indexed based arrays.

Fixed the array_pop, given Scott's comment. Thanks for catching that!

Fixed the fatal error, I guess empty cannot be used with end like I had it. The above code will no longer catch null / false if that is needed you can assign a variable from the end function and test that like so:

```
$end_item = end($transport);
if (empty($end_item)) { 
    array_pop($transport); 
}
```

Sorry for posting incorrect code. The above I tested.

Comment: so the first array of the transport is empty then delete ?

Comment: I am not understanding the second question fully, please re-elaborate. Your wording is kinda garbled imo. But hopefully, this will give you enough information to work that out on your own. But to delete a full array, unset works.

Comment: @Adam Ramadhan, `if ($transport[count($transport)-1] === '')`

Comment: Right, the code I gave you should only delete the last item of the array if the first item is empty. I believe the code I wrote above does what you want. Give it a try and see, if not try re-working it and reading up a bit more on how arrays works.

Comment: @rodic, you rock. thats a killer if :) @premiso thanks mate, ive edited my post earlier :) so its clearer. ( please see number 3 with a ship ) but if it is empty then your answer is perfect.

Comment: using array_pop makes more sense, as it will work with both associative hashes and index based arrays.

Comment: array_pop returns the last element of the array. Your example code will overwrite the entire array with the element the OP does not want.

Comment: btw its an , Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context :|

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed it, but keep Scott's as the answer imo. He deserves it for catching the obvious issues.

Comment: +1 works great ! . well yes he is, there is a slight performance distance, ( im useing xdebug ) .

Comment: Which is better on performance (just curious)? I would put Scotts given he uses count as appose to end and array_pop. But still good information to know :)

Comment: Scott's solution will have better performance if you assign the count to a variable before hand and use that, rather than call count() twice.

Comment: @BradFJacobs, is empty() a typo? I think you should check if it is not empty. Then it would be something like if(!empty()){}. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @sangam, it is not a typo. The code posted works as requested from the original post. If the end of the array is an empty string (""), then pop it off the array. Check the original question and you will see that he only wants it to delete the last element from the array, if that value is "".

Answer (score 17):

for # 1,

```
$transport=array_slice($transport,0,count($transport)-1)
```

Comment: There's no need to get the array length: `array_slice($transport, 0, -1)`

Answer (score 13):

You can simply do that by [`array_pop()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_pop.asp) function:

```
array_pop($transport);
```

Comment: For those who prefer php.net over w3schools.com -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php

Answer (score 3):

```
$endvalue = & end($transport);
array_pop($endvalue);
```